# Comparing date field in a form with current date

Tags: django

I am trying to check with an if statement if the date entered in a form is before the current date. If so write to an object in the model. I am also not sure if there are a better way of doing this.

**I get this error**

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'DateField' and 'datetime.date'
```

**My view:**

```
class ActionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    login_url = '/scrty/login/'
    template_name = "nodiso/actioncreate.html"
    form_class = forms.LeadActionCreateForm
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('nodisoapp:leaddetail', kwargs['pk'] )

  def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    return reverse("nodisoapp:leaddetail", kwargs={'pk': 
    self.kwargs['pk']})

  def form_valid(self, form):
     if form.fields['Duedate'] < datetime.date.today():
        self.object.overdue = 1
    else:
        pass
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.lead_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    self.object.creator = self.request.user.firstname
    self.object.save()
    return super(ActionCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**The Model:**

```
class LeadActions(models.Model):
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Leads)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    crdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Duedate = models.DateField()
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    overdue = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**The form:**

```
class LeadActionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LeadActions
        fields = ['name','Duedate']
```

Comment: If i change this it give me this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Duedate'

Comment: nevermind then, sorry

Comment: try to `print form.fields['Duedate']`, I think this sould be `form.fields['Duedate'].date < datetime.date.today()`

Comment: Then I get this error 'DateField' object has no attribute 'date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already pull out the unsaved model from the form here:

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
```

Why not read the `Duedate` directly from the model instance, and set the `overdue` flag accordingly ?

```
is_overdue = self.object.Duedate > datetime.date.today()
self.object.overdue = 1 if is_overdue else None
```

Complete code:

```
class ActionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
     login_url = '/scrty/login/'
     template_name = "nodiso/actioncreate.html"
     form_class = forms.LeadActionCreateForm
     # success_url = reverse_lazy('nodisoapp:leaddetail', kwargs['pk'] )

     def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
          return reverse("nodisoapp:leaddetail", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})

     def form_valid(self, form):
         self.object = form.save(commit=False)
         is_overdue = self.object.Duedate > datetime.date.today()
         self.object.overdue = 1 if is_overdue else None

         self.object.lead_id = self.kwargs['pk']
         self.object.creator = self.request.user.firstname
         self.object.save()
         return super(ActionCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```